# How to create remember me checkbox to remember session until user Logout explicitly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

If user directly close their browser without clicking logout then next time they open browser its session will be maintained as it is till they logout explicitly by clicking Logout button

I want to do it in vb.net !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pass `true` as second parameter when emitting the authentication cookie:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Username, true)
```

This will create a persistent authentication cookie on the client whose expiration is handled by the timeout property in your web.config:

```
<forms 
   loginUrl="~/login.aspx" 
   defaultUrl="~/default.aspx"
   protection="All"
   timeout="3600"
</forms>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx).